# AWS Cloud Directory - unable to determine node type

Tags: amazon-web-services

When trying to run AWS clouddirectory JDK to create an object, I always get this ERROR:

> Unable to determine if node is one of LeafNode, Node, Policy, Index
> (Service: CloudDirectory, Status Code: 400, Request ID:
> 3448687c-d30f-434e-a4e6-76fbb057f5f1)

**TestAWSCloudDirectory.java** code snippet:

```java
package com.pontusvision.graphutils;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.DefaultCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.clouddirectory.CloudDirectoryClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.clouddirectory.model.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class TestAWSCloudDirectory {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DefaultCredentialsProvider credentials = null;
    try {
      credentials =  DefaultCredentialsProvider.create(); // where is the file ?!
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new Exception(
        "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
          "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
          "location, and is in valid format.",
        e);
    }

    CloudDirectoryClient client = CloudDirectoryClient.builder()
      .credentialsProvider(credentials).build();

    AttributeKey attributeKey = AttributeKey.builder().schemaArn("***********************************************************")
      .facetName("DynamicObjectFacet")
      .name("Person_Natural").build();

    TypedAttributeValue attributeValue = TypedAttributeValue.fromStringValue("Leo");
    AttributeKeyAndValue attrib = AttributeKeyAndValue.builder().key(attributeKey).value(attributeValue).build();

    SchemaFacet schemaFacet = SchemaFacet.builder().facetName("DynamicObjectFacet").schemaArn("***********************************************************").build();

    Collection<AttributeKeyAndValue> objectAttributeList = new ArrayList<>();
    objectAttributeList.add(attrib);
    ObjectReference objectReference = ObjectReference.builder().selector("/").build();


    client.createObject(CreateObjectRequest.builder().directoryArn("***********************************************************")
      .objectAttributeList(objectAttributeList)
      .schemaFacets(schemaFacet)
      .build());

    client.close();

  }
}
```

**pom.xml** aws and cloud-directory dependencies:

```xml
(...)
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>clouddirectory</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.26</version>
    </dependency>
(...)
```

Any suggestions on what I can do?